# Should I care about appropriate variable/integer literals in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm developing a C++ game engine. A question has popped to my head.
Let's imagine this constructor:

```
Vector2f::Vector2f(float x, float y)
: x(x), y(y) {}
```

We can call in those 2 ways:

```
Vector2f(2.0, 3.5); //option 1
Vector2f(2.0f, 3.5f); //option 2
```

When in Visual Studio I hold my mouse over *right values* passed to constructor it says *(double)(2.0)* or *(double)(3.5)* or *(float)(2.0f)* *(float)(3.5)*. So I guess it makes some conversions on fly. **Should I care about this?** Or maybe simply compiler will optimize this anyway. Beacuse this seems like premature optimization but I guess I could switch to use appropriate literals anywhere where I deal with *right values*. This question also expands to using 'u' suffix etc. when writing code like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0u; i < max; i++) //this?
for (size_t i = 0; i < max; i++) //or this?
```

Comment: `size_t` would be `0zu`, not `0u`.

Comment: There's no runtime cost, the conversion will be done at compile-time (if you have optimizations enabled, at least). A more interesting question is whether writing `float x = ...; x *= 0.1;` without `f` is ok or not, because in the first case the arithmetic will be done in `double`s instead of `float`s. But I think there's also a rule that a compiler is allowed to perform floating-point arithmetic using more precision than you asked for, so this is moot.

Comment: This sounds like a general C++ question that's not specific to game development. You can post such question on https://stackoverflow.com, where they usually receive much faster answers (if they haven't been asked and answered already).

Comment: @DMGregory This isn't really an answer, it boils down to "it's moot". That's why I decided to leave it as a comment.

Comment: Adding `f` looks cleaner/more consistent to me personally. If it does to you too, I suggest enabling the appropriate compiler warnings (`-Wconversion` in GCC/Clang, MSVC has something too), and then keeping the compiler happy. I don't think any compiler will warn on `size_t i = 0` since that's a lossless conversion (so I wouldn't bother with suffixes there). MSVC won't even warn on `float x = 0.5;` because `0.5` is representable exactly as both `float` and `double`, so there's no lossy conversion.

Comment: A reason why you'd want to be pedantic on using the `f` or not is when using templates and type deduction. Say you have a `template <typename T> bool equivalent(T first, T second) {...}`, having `bool e = equivalent(myVarFloat, 0.0);` will prevent compilation as the compiler will not do type conversion and will try to find a function that matches `equivalent(float, double)`, which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting discussion!

Answer (score 1):

This code will throw warning 4305: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4305?view=msvc-170

This is a Level 1 warning so it should be thrown by your compiler in all cases unless you have warnings (or this specific warning) disabled.

The main thing to worry about here is that there may be truncation of the value (or loss of precision) due to conversion from a higher-precision to a lower-precision data type, but that obviously does not apply to all cases.

If in doubt I would just use the appropriate suffixes.